# Rails Way of Grouping By an Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know I am making this more difficult than it needs to be. There has to be a rails way of accomplishing this task. To demonstrate: here are two models:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blogs

  def to_s
    name
  end
end

#app/models/blog.rb
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
    delegate :name, to: :user, prefix: true, allow_nil: true

  def to_s
    title
  end
end
```

So what I want to do is group all of the `blogs` by the associated `user`.  Then I want to list those `blogs` per each `user`.

**Key Detail**: not all `blogs` have an associated `user`.  Some have `user_id = nil`.  Here is a listing of the blogs to demonstrate (last two blogs have `user_id = nil`):

[image: listing blogs]

So I got what I wanted to work.  But the solution is not easy to read, and I know there must be some way to accomplish this using [Rails' query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).  I couldn't figure it out though, so I hacked together my own solution below:

```
#app/controllers/admin_controller.rb
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @group_blogs_by_user = {}
    User.all.pluck(:name).each{|user| @group_blogs_by_user[user] = []}
    @group_blogs_by_user[nil] = [] #provide nil category when no user_id was specified for a blog

    Blog.all.each {|blog| @group_blogs_by_user[blog.user_name].push(blog)}

    @group_blogs_by_user.reject!{ |_ , v|v.empty?} #do not show users that have no blogs
  end
end
```

And here is the view to display it:

```
#app/views/admin/index.html.erb
<h1>Showing Count of Blogs per User</h1>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Blogs Count</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
        <% @group_blogs_by_user.each do |user, blogs_of_this_user| %>      
        <tr>
      <td><%= user || "No User Specified"%></td>
      <td><%= blogs_of_this_user.size %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<hr>

<h1>Showing Breakdown of Blogs per User</h1>
<% @group_blogs_by_user.each do |user, blogs_of_this_user| %>
  <h3><%= (user || "No User Specified") + " (#{blogs_of_this_user.size} blogs)" %></h3>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <th>Blog ID</th>
        <th>Created At</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% blogs_of_this_user.each do |blog| %>
      <tr>
        <td> <%= link_to(blog.id, blog)%></td>
        <td> <%= blog.created_at.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")%></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

And here is what it renders, which is what I want:

[image: Blogs Grouped by User]

I run into this situation all the time where I want to group a table by some association, and I find myself continually hacking together a solution.  How can I do this the rails way with Rails' Query Interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the blogs from a user and print the username, blog_id and blog count

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <%= user.name %>
    <%= user.blogs.count %>
    <% user.blogs.each do |blog|%>
        <%= blog.id %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

To get the amount of blogs with no user

```
<%= Blog.where(user: nil).count %>
```

I hope I got your question right and this helps!

Comment: Yeah pretty much this. Definitely don't have that "Blog.where..." query in the view though. Move that to a model. Delegate count to blogs too.

Comment: Wow: it is as simple as looking at it from the direction of the other association.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: @baron816 how do you delegate count to `Blog` and/or how do you delegate `where(user:nil)` to `Blog`?  I only know how to delegate to attributes for a model.

Comment: Don’t forget to apply [eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) for your users and blogs to avoid an N+1 query `User.includes(:blogs).all`. Check out [bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) to easily detect such cases.

Comment: same way you delegated name. delegate :count, to: :blogs, prefix: true. You don't delegate where. You just have a method or scope in your Blog class that does the query.

Comment: I always recommend having just passing in one instance variable from your controller to your view (the controller you had before was far too bloated). So figure out how to pass in users and the blogs in a single instance variable (hint: use a non-active record ruby class).

Comment: as baron816 pointed out: its better to move the blog_count into a controller, or even better a model instead of inside the view.